does storage provider have to be of type char,unsigned char or std::byte? or can it be any Type?
is this well-defined or UB?
alignas(alingof(T)) char buffer[sizeof(T)];

auto* p = new(buffer) T;
    
// use p
p->~T(); // destroy at end

does buffer have to be of type char,unsigned char, or std::byte?
or can it be any type like an int?
alignas(alignof(T)) int buffer[sizeof(T)/(sizeof(*buffer) + ((sizeof(T)%sizeof(*buffer)!=0)];


You should write alignas(T), not alignas(alignof(T)). Furthermore, in the second example, you likely committed a typo, swapping alignof() and alignas().

as long as the memory has the correct alignment and enough size for the object what the actual storage object is doesn't matter.

The advantage of a byte buffer is that it can match the exact size. As you noticed, having 4.5 ints is kind of bothersome, and easy to get wrong.

It does not have to be any specific type.
However, there is formally a special case if the array element type is unsigned char or std::byte. In that case, creating the T object will not end the lifetime of the array object. The array object will instead provide storage for the new T object and the new T object will be nested within the array object.
For any other element type, including char, creating the T object within its storage will end the lifetime of the array. That's not directly a concern for your usage.
If however, the element type has a non-trivial destructor, then ending the lifetime of the array elements is an issue when you reach the point where normally the destructor would be called implicitly. If you do not restore equivalent new objects for each array element so that they are within its lifetime when that point is reached, then the program will have undefined behavior per [basic.life]/10.
(Btw. I think that the linked paragraph should say "another object of the original type within its lifetime" instead of just "another object of the original type". Maybe the usage of "occupy" is supposed to already account for lifetime, though. There is probably more generally a defect in that it isn't clearly specified on which object the implicit destructor call happens. If the implicit destructor call happens outside the lifetime of the object, regardless of whether it is trivial, then the behavior is undefined.)
Also, the element type must not be const-qualified. Otherwise the attempt at storage reuse has undefined behavior per [basic.life]/11.
And technically you should be writing ::new(static_cast<void*>(buffer)) T or std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer)) instead of new(buffer) T. Otherwise you might accidentally call the wrong operator new.
The obvious benefit of char, unsigned char or std::byte is that the size calculation is much easier because their sizes are guaranteed to be 1. And std::byte has the additional benefit of making it clear that the array is intended to either store raw bytes of information or to provide storage for another object. char and unsigned char are generally arithmetic types.
In any case, trying to read/write the elements of the array after the placement-new will be UB. This is not a way to circumvent the type aliasing rules. Only access through the pointer returned by new will generally be safe.

so reading the array of unsigned char and std byte is allowed after placement new? but what about cwg2489

@user24551355 It currently isn't, but it is probably intended to be allowed. It should probably result in reading the object representation of the nested object, i.e. the same as if you accessed through reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p). That's also currently not specified correctly.

@user24551355 CWG2489 removed char from the list that can provide storage as my answer also reflects. Still, for what you are trying to do you do not need the array to provide storage. You are just interested in reusing the storage of the array.

@user117232522 oh okay I think i get any type storage can be reused but it cannot "provice" God the standard is hard to read and understand do you have any tips for how to read it?

I think reintrepret_casting into unsigned or std byte is allowed think these are allowed to alias

@user24551355 Definitions of phrases in italic should be treated like definitions in mathematical theorems. Even if "reuse storage" and "provide storage" sound similar, do not make any implicit assumptions about their relation. Just look where the same phrase is used in the standard. These are the only contexts for which it matters. Unfortunately the object system still has a few specification issues which doesn't make it easy to follow either.

@user24551355  If I don't understand the intent somewhere I try to search https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues, https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html, https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi, https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues and here for related discussion. With some luck one can find direct comments/answers from committee members.

@user24551355 Yes, as I said, the intention is clearly for access through unsigned char and std::byte to be allowed which is why they are exempt in the aliasing rule. However, the semantics of that are currently not specified correctly. See e.g. https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/592 and https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/548. And also, specifically discussing the case of arrays providing storage, see https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/416.
